# (Spring Boot) Why doesn't the Controller's post method request function start when I submit the form?

Tags: spring, forms, maven, spring-boot, freemarker

In a Spring Boot project, I've made a view of form, and two controller functions using that view, each of their methods are GET and POST. However, if I submit the form, it doesn't get into the POST method function. What should I do to make the function work?

This uses Spring Boot(Maven), freemarker, and MySQL.

This is a part of the controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/join", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView join() {
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("form");
        mv.addObject("layout", "form");
        mv.addObject("view", "createMember");
        mv.addObject("viewmsg", "Sign In");
        mv.addObject("action", "/member/join");
        Member member = new Member();
        mv.addObject("member", member);
        return mv;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/join", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView create(@ModelAttribute("member") Member member, ModelAndView mv) {
        System.out.println("bbbb");
        try {
            memberService.create(member);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            mv.addObject("layout", "form");
            mv.addObject("view", "createMember");
            mv.addObject("viewmsg", "Sign In");
            mv.addObject("action", "/member/join");
            mv.addObject("member", member);
            mv.addObject("error", e.getMessage());

            return mv;
        }

        mv.setViewName("home");
        mv.addObject("view", "home");
        mv.addObject("member", member);
        return mv;
    }
```

And this is a part of form.ftl:

```
<form class="mdl-card mdl-shadow-2dp mdl-cell--12-col" method="post" action="${action}">
    <#include "content/form/${view}.ftl">
</form>
```

This is createMember.ftl:

```
<div class="mdl-card__supporting-text">
    <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label">
        <input class="mdl-textfield__input" type="text" id="nameField" name="name">
        <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="nameField">Name</label>
    </div>
    <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label">
        <input class="mdl-textfield__input" type="text" id="idField" name="id">
        <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="idField">ID (6 - 15 letters english/number)</label>
    </div>
    <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label">
        <input class="mdl-textfield__input" type="password" id="passwordField" name="password">
        <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="passwordField">Password (6 - 15 letters english/number/symbols)</label>
    </div>
    <#if error??>
        <p>${error}</p>
    </#if>
</div>
```

I made the create() function print "bbbb" when it starts, but "bbbb" is not printed. So I guess that it doesn't even go inside that function. What should I do to make it work?

Comment: How you are hitting the POST API?
Did you checked the request content?
If Yes, what you are getting in response - Status Code/Any error?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what do you mean by 'hit the POST API'. By the way, it the POST controller doesn't even start, so I have no way to check the request content.